# How to Upgrade PHP to 5.4.10 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: php, centos

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
  CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

# php -v
  PHP 5.3.3

# yum update php
  No Packages marked for Update
```

How do I upgrade to the latest version **[PHP 5.4.10 (Current stable)](http://php.net/downloads.php)** ?

Comment: Unless you need to, generally you don't.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I need too, there is a core defect that is affecting the development of an application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the remi repository, which provides PHP 5.4 as well as MySQL 5.5 and some other LAMP related stuff not available with CentOS base or EPEL. If you use this repository, I strongly recommend the yum-versionlock plugin to ensure that your version of PHP remains on the 5.4 branch.

Comment: `yum-versionlock plugin` is used too force point to the remi repo so when I `yum update php` I am not overiding current version?

Comment: You would use it to ensure that you remain on 5.4, and don't unexpectedly get 5.5 after it hits release a few months from now.

Answer (score 8):

You can use remi like Michael Hampton suggested, but for sake of completeness, you can also compile your own php.

### Download

You can download the latest version of [php 5.4.10 from here](http://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.10.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror). Or in the event that my link is outdated by the time someone else sees this, you can go to [main php download page](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) and navigate as well.

### Dev Tools

You'll need basic development tools, and you should be able to get that through a group install.

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

### Required Libraries

You'll also need bunch of libraries to compile PHP. The following is a mere **sample** list. You may need to adjust depending on additional modules you are installing.

```
yum install libxml2-devel httpd-devel libXpm-devel gmp-devel libicu-devel \
    t1lib-devel aspell-devel openssl-devel bzip2-devel libcurl-devel \
    libjpeg-devel libvpx-devel libpng-devel freetype-devel readline-devel \
    libtidy-devel libxslt-devel
```

Another common library often used is mcrypt (`libmcrypt-devel`), but that's available under rpmforge and not the base.

### Compiling

Once all the requirements are set, actual compilation is fairly simple.

Extract the php you downloaded earlier and enter directory.

```
tar jxf php-5.4.*.tar.bz2
cd php-5.4.10
```

Configure the PHP with stuff you want enabled.

```
./configure --enable-zip --[etc. This list can get pretty long...]
```

You can see a full list of [PHP configuration options here](http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php).

Then finalize with build.

```
make
make install
```

Now you have php 5.4.* on your Centos 6.

Answer (score 8):

### Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

### CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

### Update your PHP:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install httpd php php-common
```

*CentOS 6.3/6.2/6.1/6/5.8 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6.3/6.2/6.1/6/5.8*

### Update your modules:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysql php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: If this is for a production machine I'd strongly recommend that `remi-test` is *not* enabled.